# Find all entities in a year with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data and I have an entity called `Event` with a field `eventDate`, which is a `java.util.Date`.

I would like to find all events in the year, so I first tried to write a method signature:

```
List<Event> findAllByEventDateYear(String symbol, int year);
```

But of course it doesn't work, my second attempt was to use Between:

```
List<Event> findAllByEventDateBetween(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd);
```

and to make the method more useable, I added the following to the Service:

```
private List<Event> findAllByEventDateYear(int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date dateStart = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 11 = december
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    Date dateEnd = cal.getTime();

    List<Event> quotes = eventDao.findAllByEventDateBetween(dateStart, dateEnd);
    return events;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this with Spring Data?

Comment: I would stick with making the repo provide a query for dates between two values, and if I want a query for a year, or any other such pre-defined range, I'm happy to have a service method which works out the limits of the range before passing it to the query. At least that way, your code is reasonably portable across time zones. Especially if you use the Joda or Java 8 date/time classes. And maybe use LocalDate instead, which would fix the bug you have due to ignoring the time.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for the solution

```
LocalDate instance = LocalDate.now().withYear(year);
LocalDate dateStart = instance.with(firstDayOfYear());
LocalDate dateEnd = instance.with(lastDayOfYear());
eventDao.findAllByEventDateBetween(dateStart, dateEnd);
```